# Handling php row values and grouping PHP MYSQL WHILE & Forloop

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

From my previous question [Handling while loop and grouping MYSQL PHP Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302029/handling-while-loop-and-grouping-mysql-php-values) - I'm here again with some problem
Here is my problem explained below.

## Table

```
author_id   author_name   author_book     rating  

1           A1          ABC             5
1           A1          DEF             6
2           A2          PPP             8
3           A3          FFF             9
```

## Output

```
    author_id  author_name  author_book     rating  
        1           A1      ABC             5
                    A1      DEF             6

        2           A2      PPP             8

        3           A3      FFF             9
```

## Expected Output

```
    Author ID       Author Name        Author Book         Rating
        1              A1               ABC                 5
                                        DEF                 6

        2              A2               PPP                 8

        3              A3               FFF                 9
```

## Code

```
    <?php

    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test');
    $query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM author_master ORDER BY author_id');
    $books = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $books[$row['author_id']][] = $row;
    }
    ?>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Author ID</th>
                <th>Author Book</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($books as $author_id => $values): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $author_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php foreach($values as $author_book) {echo $author_book['author_name'] . '<br/>';} ?></td>
                    <td><?php foreach($values as $author_book) {echo $author_book['author_book'] . '<br/>';} ?></td>
                    <td><?php foreach($values as $author_book) {echo $author_book['rating'] . '<br/>';} ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I know the problem is with the second  that i'm looping. But how to fix it.

Also, I'm using many foreach in my php code. Is there anyway this can be optimized.

Thanks again,

EDIT:

My biggest concern is how to optimize the code instead of using many foreach for getting the values.
Also, don't insist me to use mysqli or pdo, since this is my client request and he wants to use mysql only desperately

Kimz

Comment: I would recommend putting the values you obtain from the database in objects. I could explain in more detail in an answer if you like. also is author id and name always the same?

Comment: I am not sure but can you try adding `rowspan=<no-of-loops>` for the first `<td>` if the values are same and skip other `<td>`'s in the same column. Sorry for my lazy answer. I will surely try to write a code when I get free time.

Comment: @kpp - yes please. i need your help desperately.

Comment: Probably simplifying your your select query will reduce complexity, you can group data on author_id.

Comment: @kpp won't that query return an object?

Comment: @Ciaran Reen I believe it returns a multidimensional array.

Comment: @user3350885 I need some extra information, do you want to filter out duplicates in all columns or just the authorname?

Comment: @kpp According to the man it will return an object http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @CiaranReen yes a mysqli object, from wich you can extract the result like this `while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())` This however is not an object, this is a associative array http://us2.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php My recommendation was turning this array into an object

Comment: You won't need to though. Looking at his output vs expected output, it seems to me he just needs to select distinct (or group by) on author name.

Comment: yeah thats why I would like to know if only authorname doubles need to be removed or not, if it need to remove all doubles everywhere then its easier using an object structure or a lot cleaner and faster at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an easy and quick way to resolve doubles a class structure can be uses. in which you make an class for Authors and Books, where Authours can have mulitple books, if you wish you could go a layer deeper where books can have mulitple ratings or make an id have multilpe authors like this, but that is not for my example. If this is required though let me know I can easily change it.

```
<?php
class Author{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $books = array();

    public function __construct($id, $name){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addBook($book, $rating){
        $newBook = new Book($book, $rating);
        if(!in_array($newbook, $books){
            array_push($books, $newBook);
        }
    }
}

class Book{
    public $book;
    public $rating;

    public function __construct($book, $rating){
        $this->book = $book;
        $this->rating = $rating;   
    }
    //to make it easy checking for duplicates.
    public function __tostring(){
        return $this->book.$this->rating;
}

//yourcode
$books = array;
$newBook = null;
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   if($newBook->id != $row['author_id'];){
       $newBook = new Author($row['author_id'], $row['author_name']);
       array_push($books, $newBook);
   }
   $newBook->addBook($row['author_book'], $row['rating']);
}?>

//and then your foreach.
<?php foreach($books as $author): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $author->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $author->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php foreach($author->books as $book) {echo $book->book.'<br/>';}?></td>
        <td><?php foreach($author->books as $book) {echo $book->rating.'<br/>';}?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is an OOPHP approach, which works really well in cases like this, because it causes easy modifying if this is required.

Answer (score 1):

I just make some changes in you code. I don't know if it is what you want. Here is the coding.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'test', 'test', "test");
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM author_master ORDER BY author_id');
$books = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $books[$row['author_id']][$row['author_name']][] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Author ID</th>
            <th>Author Book</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($books as $author_id => $values): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $author_id; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($values as $ankey => $author_book) {
                        echo $ankey . '<br/>';
                    }
                    ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($values as $author_book) {
                        foreach ($author_book as $br) {
                            echo $br['author_book'] . '<br/>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($values as $author_book) {
                        foreach ($author_book as $br) {
                            echo $br['rating'] . '<br/>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```